# JQuery 1.7 doesn't work with 1.4.2 Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

in my Drupal site LayerSlider works with JQuery 1.7,, when i add specific code with JQuery 1.4.2 all sliders from LayerSlider stop work, could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned yourself, LayerSlider requires jQuery version 1.7.

To make it work with Drupal, you'll have to install the [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module.

> Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of jQuery.
>
> Updates...
>
> - Drupal 5 to jQuery 1.2.6
> - Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
> - Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.1, 1.7.1, or 1.8.2 (site administrator's choice), and jQuery UI 1.8.11
> - Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.1/1.7.1/1.8.2, 1.9.1, 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.1 (in dev branch 7.x-2.x-dev)

Comment: Do you see the updated version of jQuery at `admin/reports/status`? It should work ideally, unless there is some misconfiguration in the slider.

Comment: yes there is "jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.2" in front of jQuery Update

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the code which you wrote for jQuery 1.4.2?

Comment: @justfemale The link which you posted, contains script that includes jQuery 1.4.2. I think this conflicts with the jQuery version that is already present after the upgrade. One question though : Are you entering the code into a block. If so how? In an iframe? Is it possible to include the rest of the script apart from the including of jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: am adding the code as script tag in the block having the link source, but i will try to put the code in file and separate the including of jQuery and  jQuery UI ,,, thank you